# How can I start a program (file.exe) inside Autodesk Maya

Tags: python, maya, autodesk

Hello everyone and thanks for the help.
I am absolutely newbe to Python and I don't know anything, but what I want to do I can only do with this programming language, so sorry in advance and please help me.

The purpose is to launch an external program within Maya.
In particular what I want to do is launch the "vraydr_check.exe" program which allows me to see if the destination host is configured to receive a distributed render.

The path to the executable is usually: "C:\Program Files\Chaos Group\V-Ray\Maya 2022 for x64\bin", the command has two arguments and is composed as follows: "vraydr_check.exe -host= < myhost> -port=20207".

Now, within the maya console or from the command line I can run a python script that does what I asked but I don't know, as already said, how to do it.

Any suggestions?
Thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the module [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) in Python.

```
import subprocess
args = [
    r'C:\Program Files\Chaos Group\V-Ray\Maya 2022 for x64\bin\vraydr_check.exe',
    '-host', 
    'my_host',
    '-port',
    'my_port',
]
try:
    captured_output = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True, check=True)
    print(f'Success: {captured_output.stdout}')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f'ERROR: {e.stderr}')
```